# Python-Tkinter - Ttk ComboBox - get function returning empty string (length=0)

Tags: python-3.x, ttk

**Objective**: 
To retrieve the value selected by user in combobox using self.cbo_assign.get()

**Issue**: 
self.cbo_assign.get() is returning empty string (length=0)

**Additional Information**

I have a form on which widgets are dynamically generated. I am using a combobox to get user input. The combobox is bound to a method using widget.bind.

1. This is just part of code in which I am facing issue
2. All the variables and functions have been defined.Imports have been properly declared. I am facing problem, while user is selecting value in **cbo_assign**. The callback function is called, database is called and updated but the value of **cbo_assign** is empty string(length=0).
3. I cannot use attribute textvariable, because the widget is generated for all the records in list mail_list. Functionally, I cannot have multiple widgets tagged to same textvariable
4. I am using **self.cbo_assign.get()** to get the selected value, however it is returning empty string (length=0)
5. I tried the same code in another file (i have a test.py where I try out small snippets) and the code is working properly. I compared that file with current code, and couldnt find any difference. However in test.py, I didnt use class for designing window. Not sure, if that can have any bearing
6. The GUI is working properly, it displays the widget, lets the user select value, calls the callback, updates the database. However value tagged to combobox is empty(length=0).

**Github link** - https://github.com/tusharacc/python-read-outlook-mails/tree/master

The gui resides in gui.py and is the entry point for the application.

**Expectation**: **self.cbo_assign.get()** should return the value selected by user. The self.cbo_assign.get is called in update_assignment_details callback. I tried passing the self.cbo_assign.get as a paramater too, but even then it didnt work

Code that simulates the behaviour

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+E+S+W)
        self.user_names = [['ABC','THDG'],['GHI','ANBC'],['DEF','SODM'],['CMF','CMH'],['KDH','APE']]
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.mail_frame = Frame(self, bg='green')
        self.mail_frame.grid(row=20,column=0,sticky=N + E + S + W,padx=10,pady=10)
        self.mail_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mail_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.initiate_mail_process()

    def initiate_mail_process(self):
        self.mail_list = [['ABC']]*6
        row = 5
        for _ in self.mail_list:
            col = 0
            self.cbo_assign = ttk.Combobox(self.mail_frame, values=self.user_names)
            self.cbo_assign.grid(row=row, column=col, columnspan=5, sticky=N + S + W + E)
            self.cbo_assign.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda x: self.update_assignment_details(x))       
            col += 5
            row += 5

    def update_assignment_details(self,event):
        print (self.cbo_assign.get())

root = Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.title("TICKET ASSIGNMENT")
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mvce]. Your use of `self.cbo_assign.get()` is proper here. so the only explanation is that `self.cbo_assign` is not what you think it is, or you're calling it before the user has had a chance to enter data. Since we can't run your code, we can't see which it is.

Comment: @BryanOakley, the github link is - https://github.com/tusharacc/python-read-outlook-mails/tree/master. Earlier one of my question was downvoted, because I provided the complete code and was asked to provide only that portion that is causing the issue. Hence I kept the code snippet to only that portion. However I understand that, making a sense out of just a part of code is difficult. Hence provided the github link. Let me know if you want me to paste it my question.

Comment: @BryanOakley, as for self.cbo_assign is not what you think it is.......I checked my code for any other declaration of cbo_assign, when using print (self.cbo_assign['values']), it prints the values tagged to the combobox, I checked the callback - It is called only when event is occuring.

Comment: A github link is relatively useless. Please edit your question to include a proper [mcve]. We don't want a link to the code, and we don't want the complete code. We want you to take the time down to condense the code to the smallest possible amount of code that reproduces the problem

Comment: (This looks like a good question, but please don't ask for votes here, especially in posts - it just creates more work for editors!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to identify the root cause. The combo box is getting generated in loop. Hence self.cbo_assign is referencing to the last added combo box. So self.cbo_assign.get() is always fetching the selected value in last combo box. Hence it is empty. If event is triggered for last combobox, it will fetch the value.

The easiest solution I found (might not be the right way to do it) is to pass the cbo as parameter to event handler.The modified code is below -

```
def initiate_mail_process(self):
    self.mail_list = [['ABC']]*6
    row = 5
    for _ in self.mail_list:
        col = 0
        self.cbo_assign = ttk.Combobox(self.mail_frame, values=self.user_names)
        self.cbo_assign.grid(row=row, column=col, columnspan=5, sticky=N + S + W + E)
        self.cbo_assign.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda x,arg=self.cbo_assign: self.update_assignment_details(x,arg))
        col += 5
        row += 5
```

Thanks @Bryan for the pointers. While generating the minimal code, I was able to find the issue.

Comment: _"Thanks @Bryan for the pointers. While generating the minimal code, I was able to find the issue."_ - this is one of the main reasons we ask for a [mcve]. The act of creating it is often enough to get you to focus on the root of the problem, and figure the problem out for yourself.